# Failing to build project on m1 silicon with arm64 dependency

Tags: rust, x86-64, zeromq, apple-silicon

I am trying to get zeromq to work in my rust program, however I am getting linking issues due to the rust programming running through Rosetta (x86_64) but the zeromq library being installed on arm64. Steps to re-create:

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "zmq-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
zmq = "0.9"
```

Homebrew

```
arch -arm64 brew install zeromq
```

```
cargo build
```

Error:

```
 ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zeromq/4.3.4/lib/libzmq.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
          Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

Attempts:

Install zeromq using x86, but throws an error to install with arm

```
arch -x86_64 brew install zeromq
```